# Are there any Youtrack plugins for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, youtrack

Are there any plugins for Visual Studio 2010 that allow to work with Youtrack directly from the IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is "no".
However, you can vote for [these two](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/JT-6857) [feature requests](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/JT-6234), and chances are we'll find a way to integrate YouTrack with VS in one way or another.

Comment: Ok but is there a third party tool?

Comment: None to my knowledge. YouTrack currently integrates with IntelliJ IDEA, TeamCity, and TestLink, and that's basically all. However, it exposes a decent REST API (http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/YTD2/YouTrack+REST+API+Reference) that allows manipulating issues to an extent that is sufficient for developing a custom VS plugin.

Comment: There is a ReSharper plugin that I haven't gotten around to test yet: https://github.com/JetBrains/YouTrackForReSharper

Comment: @NiklasRingdahl The link is broken :/